# Spaces between html attributes and values?

Tags: html, formatting, spaces

Are they allowed? and do they work with all browsers?

Example:

```
<div role = "region"
     id = "some-id"
     class = "a-class another-class">
```

Comment: `role` ins't valid, the rest validates

Comment: @jackJoe - `role` is valid in HTML5. see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#wai-aria and http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#region

Comment: These are allowed since the very first HTML version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, any amount of whitespace is allowed and will work in all browsers.

From the [Attributes section of the HTML5 living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) on unquoted, single-, and double-quoted attribute value syntax:

> The attribute name, followed by zero or more ASCII whitespace, followed by a single U+003D EQUALS SIGN character, followed by zero or more ASCII whitespace, [...]

One consideration - this will add to the page size, so if bandwidth and performance are concerns, try to limit the amount of whitespace you use.

Comment: Does any amount of whitespace allows *zero-width* for quoted attributes after the attribute value? - Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23887069/367456

Comment: Not sure about that. I'd expect they should be.

Comment: If you're asking about having *no* whitespace, then.. no. That's not accepted. "Any amount" really means "one or more characters" in this context. That's also mentioned in the accepted answer on the post you linked.

Answer (score 6):

Yes they are, and they will work in all major browsers, although I would say it should be considered bad practice to include unnecessary white-space as it pointlessly increases the size of the document.

HTML, XHTML, XML and others are all variants of [SGML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html), so if you want to know what is/isn't allowed in general, have a look at that specification. You should always pass all your documents through the [W3C markup validators](http://validator.w3.org/) to ensure they are valid.

Comment: Good point. Realized I could save 20% by compressing this HTML. Thanks!

Comment: I think the benefits in readability out way the costs, especially if you use a compressor. This is especially true when using a templating preprocessor, where large attribute values can make the markup unreadable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is perfectly valid markup. Whitespace is handled nicely by all browsers.

Any time you have confusion, you can validate your code at **official W3 validation service**:

- http://validator.w3.org/