# Does HTML5 requires spaces between attributes that are of quoted values?

Tags: html

HTML does normally allow to have no spaces between attributes when attributes have values and those values are quoted.

Example ([Reference/Source](http://www.validome.org/lang/en/errors/MISC/3004)):

> In HTML-documents no White Spaces between Attributes are needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                                                                 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">                                                                                   

<html>                                                                                                                         
  <head>                                                                                                                       
    <title>no attribute space</title>                                                                                          
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">                                                   
  </head>                                                                                                                      
  <body>                                                                                                                       
    <p class="CLASS"title='TITLE'></p>                                                                                         
  </body>                                                                                                                      
</html>
```

See the third-last line:

```
    <p class="CLASS"title='TITLE'></p>                                                                                         
                   ^^
```

Now using such HTML chunk changing the doctype to HTML 5 (`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`), makes the [*experimental* W3C HTML 5 conformance checker](http://validator.w3.org/check) give an error exactly there telling me:

> Validation Output: 1 Error
>
> Error Line 9, Column 22: No space between attributes.
>
> ```
>     <p class="CLASS"title='TITLE'></p>
>                     ^
> ```

So I thought that HTML 5 is backwards compatible to how browsers deal with HTML in reality and browsers AFAIK deal with this well. So I'm a bit puzzeled at least. I also have problems to decipher the (somewhat needlessly) compilcated HTML 5 specs to be precise at this point because what I did find (W3C again, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes) it's not saying that this is (may nor must) be an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are reading a discontinued, non-normative reference. If you look at the definition of the [start tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags) in the specification (which is normative) it says:

> Then, the start tag may have a number of attributes, the syntax for which is described below. **Attributes must be separated from each other by one or more space characters**.

---

> So I thought that HTML 5 is backwards compatible to how browsers deal with HTML in reality and browsers AFAIK deal with this well.

Being compatible with real world markup is a design goal, but lots of things have been obsoleted and leaving out the space between attributes is something that almost never occurs intentionally.

Comment: I've cross checked and it looks like (by using the validator) that XHTML/XML also requires this space between attributes. Makes more and more sense, thanks for linking those specs.

Comment: For completeness: the cited text applies to HTML5 in HTML serialization (HTML syntax), whereas in XHTML serialization, general XML rules apply, and according to them, too, at least one space, tab, or newline must appear between attribute specifications; reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags

Answer (score 1):

[Section 4.3, "Elements"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) of the document you link in the question says:

> Optionally, one or more attributes, each of which must be preceded by
>   one or more space characters.

Comment: That document describes itself as a "non-normative reference". It isn't the specification. It also says "This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes"

Answer (score -2):

Usin the [W3C Official HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), having no spaces between attributes are checked as errors if you use the HTML5 Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The output message is the following:

> Line 9, Column 23: No space between attributes.

Comment: The validator is not normative (and is marked as experimental).

Comment: Why do you say that is not normative and is experimental? Where do you see that?

Comment: When you validate an HTML 5 document it includes this message before any of the results:  Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker.

The validator checked your document with an experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker. This feature has been made available for your convenience, but be aware that it may be unreliable, or not perfectly up to date with the latest development of some cutting-edge technologies.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question. The question itself says that the validator gives the "no space between attributes" message!

Comment: I know that the validator reports this, see my question, I've quoted from there *already*. No need to repeat that.