# Populate image url in the file button

Tags: php, html

i have tried to populate the value of the image in the file input. i want to keep the uploaded file in the file input. so that if i don't browse any new image, it will keep the previous one image.

```
<img src="/img/test.jpg" height="150" width="150"><br>
<input type="file" name="logo"value="<?php echo $image[0]['logo']?>">
```

so can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It may also have to do with the missing space between `name="logo"value="...` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887069/does-html5-requires-spaces-between-attributes-that-are-of-quoted-values

Comment: Well if you want to display the image you have uploaded then this isn't the correct way of doing it.

Comment: for security reasons, you cannot set value on input type file. please learn about it here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html

Answer (score 3):

Browsers don't allow you to pre-populate an `input type="file"`.

If you think about it, this makes sense...

- Why would you want to include a file path for a file that *you don't know exists*?  Your application has no idea of the state of the client-side file system.
- Why would you want to *re-upload* the *same* file every time the user re-submits the form without changes?
- The ***security*** implications of this are obvious.  Browsers clearly don't want you to specify a system file and then style the input to be hidden, thereby stealing files from users.