# Are there any disadvantages of not having a space between HTML attributes of tag other than it's not as per W3C spec?

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

According to the spec. this is not right.

```
<div class="foo"id="bar">
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#start-tags

> 4. Then, the start tag may have a number of attributes, the syntax for which is described below. Attributes must be separated from each other
>      by one or more space characters.

But I wanted to know if there any practical disadvantages of no space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does HTML5 requires spaces between attributes that are of quoted values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887069/does-html5-requires-spaces-between-attributes-that-are-of-quoted-values)

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Not duplicate because I already know that HTML 5 spec requires it.

Comment: What more practical disadvantage than "not compliant with the spec" do you want?! Parsers will be based on the spec, if you aren't compliant any or all of them could choke on your markup.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you mean search engine Parsers?

Comment: No, he means "parsers". He didn't specify parsers used by whom, so he probably means all of them.

Comment: Whoever has given downvotes or vote to close, please care to explain what is wrong with the question if you have time. Thanks.

Comment: Just... parsers. All HTML parsers. Search engines, browsers, validators, libraries, ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for letting me know. I didn't know that Search engine parsing could be impacted by not following spec (and could lead to negative SEO)

Comment: Not just SEO. Your *actual users* may not see your pages as you intend them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you know if there is a way to test this?

Comment: What do you mean *"is there a way to test this"*? Yes, the way to test it is... testing. Run end-to-end testing using a browser driver like Selenium across a range of browsers and devices/OSs that reflect your user base to test that they can use the site correctly. Generate screenshots from the tests and review them to ensure that the page is rendering correctly. Invalid markup you have to try to test *everywhere* that could parse it, that's why creating and validating valid markup is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You're depending on consistent error recovery between all the many, many different HTML parsers out there (including ones you can't test, like Google's search engine indexing bots).

It's also an unreadable mess that makes it harder for maintainers to work with.

Comment: Agree. I have started working on an existing app found many instances of no space, not sure if I try to fix this everywhere or just leave it as it is if it has no practical disadvantage.

Comment: If you're working with legacy code, don't just fix it willy nilly without testing every single change that you make. Last thing you want to do is break something that was depending on said error recovery.

Comment: @BoltClock Do you that there is a possibility of an unexpected change after having space in a specific case?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Maybe. Who knows? That's why you have to test.

Comment: @BoltClock If that happen, it will prove whether spacing matter or not. I will test. Thanks for the advice and not having spaces at the first place could be a disadvantage.

Comment: @Quentin - Ok but would I loose any SEO if Google's search engine indexing bots find no space between attributes?

Comment: @JitendraVyas — Maybe. Maybe not. This is a problem with writing invalid code for parsers that you can't test in.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine what happens when you don't .... you save space on size.  It is one good reason not too, you see html cleaners (or code cleaners in general) which compress by removing whitespace - as it's still taking bits).

Now, what happens when you do include the spaces per spec ... ever wonder why all of those types of service for compressing html (or code) has a reverse, usually with tons of features for whitespace ... ?

Readability - as humans we expect certain conventions ... spacing is one that most people are trained to recognize (not that you can't adapt to other styles).