# Difference between linking a javascript file and directly adding script into html

Tags: javascript, html

I am recreating a  javascript game which requires tables, but when I link my javascript file to my index.html the grid does not show on my browser, but when I directly add my javascript inside the script tag in my html, the grid shows on the browser.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

This is my code by referencing a js file inside html(the tables do not show)
[html with js link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iQtM.png)

This is my code without referencing a js file(tables do show)
[html without js link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJDvw.png)

This is my main.js
[main js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm7lu.png)

This is the browser without linking js file
[browser without js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LguvZ.png)

This is my browser with linking js file
[browser with js reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcFhM.png)

First I linked the js file with script src=js path but it did not work but it worked when I put the javascript directly inside the html script tag. I was wondering how I can make it work with referencing a separate js file for a cleaner html code.

Comment: Does the dev console show an error for loading the script?

Comment: @HenryWoody the dev console shows "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" -- could this be the issue? This error also shows up even when the table shows(no javascript file linked)

Comment: That doesn't sound related.

Comment: Is `main.js` in the same directory as `index.html`?

Comment: @HenryWoody yes my index.html and main.js are in the same folder

Comment: @SamLee can you update the question with file explorer screenshot, so we can tell folder structure?

Comment: Hmm, just a guess, but the file in the screenshot has not been saved, are you sure you saved the file?

Comment: Also for debugging, you might add a simple `console.log("loaded")` to the `main.js` file so you can be sure it has loaded properly just to be sure whether it's an issue with loading the script or with the script itself

Comment: @str1ng I have edited the screenshots with file explorer

Comment: @SamLee It's due to blank spaces between `src = "main.js"`, you should make it `src="main.js"`

Comment: @HenryWoody I tried again after saving but the table still does not show. I am also using the live server vs code extension

Comment: @SamLee Just remove spaces and check my answer once again, I've updated it. Copy and paste and it will work

Comment: @str1ng those spaces are valid and are not the problem (see [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064095/spaces-between-html-attributes-and-values))

Comment: @SamLee do you ever call `startGame`? That could be the issue

Comment: @HenryWoody It is indeed relevant and is the problem. 
Create simple html file and main.js file which will just go with `console.log("Something")` document and try to link script like this:
`<script src = "main.js"></script>` and then after it try
`<script src="main.js"></script>`

Comment: @HenryWoody ahh... thank you that was the issue. I never called startGame(); in my main.js. I added that line and it works! thank you so much!

Comment: @HenryWoody just one question I was wondering why the table shows when I don't call startGame() function when I didn't link the main.js and added the js directly inside my html script tag?

Comment: @str1ng It's not, and I did do that to double check before I posted to avoid adding irrelevant and incorrect information here. Again I'll point you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064095/spaces-between-html-attributes-and-values) and the [spec for HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2)

Comment: @SamLee I'm really not sure, perhaps you called the function yourself in the console? On its own, the code you posted should not have updated the table.

Comment: @HenryWoody Well, I am not either somebody who will post answers/comments that would be missguiding or not being checked. I am fully aware that whitespaces are ignored, but how are we going to explain the situation which I left screenshots for?
Btw. By using code extractor I copy pasted code of SamLee and separated javascript from HTML, exactly same result (with blankspaces I am getting "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" and after removing blank spaces it was okay. 

This could be also caused by the browser, but still...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to that your local paths are not resolving correctly. Without seeing directory structure I can't know what could be wrong.

First of all, please re-check and verify that both files `main.js` and `index.html` are in the same directory.

Alternatively, you could create folder called `js` inside of your main directory (where `index.html` is) and then move the `main.js` into that folder and try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

**index.html and main.js files must be at the same directory in order to include .js file as you did**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE (I will leave answer whole, if somebody also gets stuck, so they can troubleshoot the problem):**

The reason why it couldn't resolve path is because there was blank spaces between `src` and `=` ; when giving src, that part needs to be connected.

Just like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Take a look here:
[image]

What happens:
[image]

Comment: I removed the spaces and code looks like this "<script src="main.js"></script>" but the tables still do not show. I ran console.log("loaded") on my main.js file and it says there is a reference error:document is not defined. Is the reference error causing the problem?

Comment: @SamLee Just try to move `<script src="main.js"></script>` before closing `</body>`